# How to design a PI controller for fourth-order transfer-function?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller, tuning, designer

Fourth-order systems may render very complex characteristic equation that are difficult for tuning. Is there any method to tune controllers for these systems easily?

Comment: Does your system have dominant poles? If so, you may be able to use tuning methods for second order or first order systems.

Comment: What do you mean by "*accurately*" ? Usually the system may still work, even if the PI gains vary by a factor of 2.

Comment: Thanks AJN... I will consider the correction...